# Build Zip with goroutines panic with slice bounds out of range with capacity 4096

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm trying to improve a function to build a Zip by adding goroutines to handle each file that has to be archived.
But it ends up with a panic
`panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [4126:4096`]

The target directory contains 190 files (500 Mo).
I don't really understand what's wrong,
Thank you in advance for your help

The function :

```
func BuildArchive() error {                                                        
                                                                                   
    var files []string                                                             
    err := filepath.Walk("/tmp/dir-to-zip", func(filePath string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if info.IsDir() {                                                          
            return nil                                                             
        }                                                                          
        if err != nil {                                                            
            fmt.Println(err)                                                       
            return err                                                             
        }                                                                          
        files = append(files, filePath)                                            
                                                                                   
        return nil                                                                 
    })                                                                             
    if err != nil {                                                                
        return err                                                                 
    }                                                                              
                                                                                   
    bundle, err := os.Create("/tmp/archive.zip")                                   
    if err != nil {                                                                
        return err                                                                 
    }                                                                              
    bundleWriter := zip.NewWriter(bundle)                                          
                                                                                   
    var wg sync.WaitGroup                                                          
    wg.Add(len(files))                                                             
                                                                                   
    for _, filePath := range files {                                               
        go func(filePath string) {                                                 
            defer wg.Done()                                                        
            relPath := strings.TrimPrefix(filePath, fmt.Sprintf("%v/", filepath.Dir("/tmp/dir-to-zip")))
                                                                                   
            bundleFile, err := bundleWriter.Create(relPath)                        
            if err != nil {                                                        
                fmt.Println(err)                                                   
            }                                                                      
            fsFile, err := os.Open(filePath)                                       
            if err != nil {                                                        
                fmt.Println(err)                                                   
            }                                                                      
            _, err = io.Copy(bundleFile, fsFile)                                   
            if err != nil {                                                        
                fmt.Println(err)                                                   
            }                                                                      
                                                                                   
        }(filePath)                                                                
    }                                                                              
    wg.Wait()                                                                      
                                                                                   
    err = bundleWriter.Close()                                                     
    if err != nil {                                                                
        return err                                                                 
    }                                                                              
    return nil                                                                     
}
```

The error occurs here :

```
        _, err = io.Copy(bundleFile, fsFile)                                   
        if err != nil {                                                        
            fmt.Println(err)                                                   
        }
```

The stack trace :

```
goroutine 48 [running]:                                                            
bufio.(*Writer).Write(0xc00002a100, {0xc00041a400?, 0x3d?, 0xc00041a400?})         
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:670 +0x1c8                                    
archive/zip.(*countWriter).Write(0xc00000c138, {0xc00041a400?, 0x3d?, 0x4afa20?})
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:601 +0x2e                              
io.WriteString({0x4e7538, 0xc00000c138}, {0xc0000212c9, 0x3d})                     
    /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:314 +0x91                                           
archive/zip.writeHeader({0x4e7538, 0xc00000c138}, 0xc000220090)                    
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:422 +0x5ec                             
archive/zip.(*Writer).CreateHeader(0xc0000760a0, 0xc00021e1b0)                     
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:378 +0x797                             
archive/zip.(*Writer).Create(0x4e7698?, {0xc0000212c9, 0x3d})                      
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:223 +0x6c                              
main.BuildArchive.func2({0xc0000212c0, 0x46})                                      
    /home/simba/go/src/foobar/main.go:79 +0x1c5                                    
created by main.BuildArchive                                                       
    /home/simba/go/src/foobar/main.go:73 +0x5aa                                    
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [:4126] with capacity 4096         
                                                                                   
goroutine 6 [running]:                                                             
bufio.(*Writer).Flush(0xc00002a100)                                                
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:634 +0x171                                    
bufio.(*Writer).Write(0xc00002a100, {0xc0001b4200?, 0xc000199b20?, 0xc000199b20?})
    /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:672 +0xd8                                     
archive/zip.(*countWriter).Write(0xc00000c138, {0xc0001b4200?, 0x0?, 0xc000199b40?})
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:601 +0x2e                              
archive/zip.(*countWriter).Write(0xc000220018, {0xc0001b4200?, 0xc0001b02c0?, 0xc0001b02f0?})
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:601 +0x2e                              
compress/flate.(*huffmanBitWriter).write(...)                                      
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/huffman_bit_writer.go:136                     
compress/flate.(*huffmanBitWriter).writeCode(0xc0001b41e0?, {0x6000?, 0x22?})   
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/huffman_bit_writer.go:347 +0xe5               
compress/flate.(*huffmanBitWriter).writeTokens(0xc0001b41e0, {0xc002558000, 0x4001, 0x403f800000403f?}, {0xc0001aa900, 0x11e, 0x108129000000000f?}, {0xc0001ac100, 0x1e, 0x1e})
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/huffman_bit_writer.go:583 +0xb9               
compress/flate.(*huffmanBitWriter).writeBlock(0xc0001b41e0, {0xc002558000?, 0x20?, 0xd79?}, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/huffman_bit_writer.go:495 +0x490              
compress/flate.(*compressor).writeBlock(0xc0005a2000, {0xc002558000?, 0xc000032f00?, 0xc000199d28?}, 0x47739b?)
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/deflate.go:170 +0x9c                          
compress/flate.(*compressor).deflate(0xc0005a2000)                                 
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/deflate.go:509 +0x59b                         
compress/flate.(*compressor).write(0xc0005a2000, {0xc00256a000?, 0x8000, 0xf311b6fd?})
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/deflate.go:554 +0x82                          
compress/flate.(*Writer).Write(...)                                                
    /usr/local/go/src/compress/flate/deflate.go:712                                
archive/zip.(*pooledFlateWriter).Write(0xc00020c040?, {0xc00256a000?, 0x8000?, 0x4af140?})
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/register.go:51 +0xc5                             
archive/zip.(*countWriter).Write(...)                                              
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:601                                    
archive/zip.(*fileWriter).Write(0xc000222000, {0xc00256a000, 0x8000, 0x8000})   
    /usr/local/go/src/archive/zip/writer.go:533 +0x97                              
io.copyBuffer({0x4e7558, 0xc000222000}, {0x4e7678, 0xc0001f8008}, {0x0, 0x0, 0x0})
    /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:428 +0x204                                          
io.Copy(...)                                                                       
    /usr/local/go/src/io/io.go:385                                                 
main.BuildArchive.func2({0xc00001c0c0, 0x35})                                      
    /home/simba/go/src/foobar/main.go:89 +0x385                                    
created by main.BuildArchive                                                       
    /home/simba/go/src/foobar/main.go:73 +0x5aa                                    
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`zip.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Writer) is not safe for concurrent use. You launch multiple goroutines, each creating and writing to zip entries (files).

[`Writer.Create()`](https://pkg.go.dev/archive/zip#Writer.Create) documents that:

> Create adds a file to the zip file using the provided name. It returns a Writer to which the file contents should be written.
>
> [...] **The file's contents must be written to the io.Writer before the next call to Create, CreateHeader, or Close.**

You can't create a zip concurrently. `io.Writer`s of each zip entry write to the same underlying file (or to the same `io.Writer` in general), even if your app doesn't panic or crash, the resulting zip archive will likely be invalid.